# How to lookup data and print values based on criteria in R?

Tags: r, database, csv, sqldf

So I have a csv file that has 12 columns of data, what I want to do is get specific values from the CSV file based on the desired criteria

[image]

A snip of the data is provided, so I have this list of Maps:

`Maps <- c("Nuke","Vertigo","Inferno","Mirage","Train","Overpass","Dust2")`

The goal is to get CTWinProb & TWinProb values for each of the maps in the Map list, e.g.
CTWinProbs;

Nuke = 0.5758

Dust2 = 0.4965

Inferno = 0.4885

etc and vice versa for TWinProb

So far I have been using sqldf library which is very tedious, this is what I am currently doing:

`T1NukeCT <- sqldf("select CTWinProb from Team1 where MapName like '%Nuke%'")`

which outputs T1NukeCT = 0.5758

and repeating for each Map and then again for TWinProb

I am sure there is an easier way, just quite new to using R so am not 100% on the best method here or how to go about doing it in a less tedious manner

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `WHERE IN (...)` clause:

```
Maps <- c("Nuke","Vertigo","Inferno","Mirage","Train","Overpass","Dust2")
where_in <- paste0("('", paste(Maps, collapse="','"), "')")
sql <- paste0("SELECT CTWinProb FROM Team1 WHERE MapName IN ", where_in)
T1NukeCT <- sqldf(sql)
```

To be clear, the SQL query generated by the above script is:

```
SELECT CTWinProb
FROM Team1
WHERE MapName IN ('Nuke','Vertigo','Inferno','Mirage','Train','Overpass','Dust2')
```

Answer (score 0):

What output/results are you looking for exactly?

If you want results in `R`, these are two simple functions to return the desired values.

They require the `dplyr` package to be loaded.

```
library(dplyr)
YourData <- read_csv("./yourfile/.csv")

CTWinFunc <- function(x){
YourData %>% filter(MapName == x) %>% pull(CTWinProb)}

TWinFunc <- function(x){
YourData %>% filter(MapName == x) %>% pull(TWinProb)}
```

Now `CTWinFunc("Nuke")` should return CTWinProb result for Nuke, ie: 0.5758

And `TWinFunc("Nuke")` should return TWinProb result for Nuke, ie: 0.4242

If you want to return a vector with all the results together, I guess you could use the `sapply()` function. Something like this...

```
TWins <- sapply(Maps, TWinFunc)
TWins[lengths(TWins)==0] <- NA
TWins <- unlist(TWins)
```

And this should give you a table with the results:

```
cbind(Maps, Twins)
```

Of course, it seems like all this data is already in the original table and you could just subset that.

```
YourData[,c(4,11,12)]
```